# Is this vulnerable for XSS?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

Is below Java Script code vulnerable for XSS? This is invoked from login page. If error is found in the page, again login page will be hit with the error message.

```
if(userName.length==0)
{ 
 initialMsg="Please enter a User Name"; 
 errorMessage+=encodeHTML(initialMsg);
 document.writeln("<form name=\"errForm\" method=\"POST\" action=\"http://loginPageURLGoesHere\">");
 document.writeln("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"errorMessage\" value=\"" + errorMessage + "\">"); 
 document.writeln("</form>"); 
 document.errForm.submit();
 return false;
}

function encodeHTML(s)
{
  return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Doing all checks at server side is a solution for fixing XSS. But, I want to know if above encoding will help to prevent XSS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the initial value of `errorMessage`. As you are appending to it, it is not possible to see from your code what it already contains. The encoding should be done when output to guard against any possible [DOM Based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS).

i.e. `document.writeln("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"errorMessage\" value=\"" + encodeHTML(errorMessage) + "\">");`

Also, don't forget to encode single quote.

You should make sure that `http://loginPageURLGoesHere` correctly sanitises the `errorMessage` POSTed to it before output to guard against regular [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS).

Comment: So, instead of `errorMessage+=encodeHTML(initialMsg);` I should do this `document.writeln("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"errorMessage\" value=\"" + encodeHTML(errorMessage) + "\">");`  ?

Comment: Yes - I always encode at point of output, or name my variable in such as way to indicate that it has already been encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does, especially, since nothing used in the string concatenation comes from user input, so even without `encodeHTML`, it couldn't be exploited in a useful way.

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't help. An attacker can bypass the page that runs that JS entirely and send the victim directly to `http://loginPageURLGoesHere`.

Comment: In case an attacker doesn't bypass but he tampers with the output (errorMessage)... Does the above code will be able to prevent it?